# Passing constant value to template

Tags: c++, templates, itk

I am using a template class that has two templated parameters

```
itk::Image<PIXELTYPE,DVALUE>
```

At the time of reading the image I will get information about type and dimension of the image. As there are 11 possible values of type and 3 values of dimension (2,3,4) each time I read an image and have to apply the operation I am doing it as following:

```
std::string type = IOBase->GetComponentTypeAsString(IOBase->GetComponentType());
const unsigned int dim = IOBase->GetNumberOfDimensions();

if(dim ==3)
{
    if(type == "unsigned_char")
    {
        typedef itk::Image<unsigned char,3> ImageType;
        //apply operation
    }
    else if(type == "char")
    {
        typedef itk::Image< char,3> ImageType;
        //apply operation

    }
    else if(type ==....so on 
}
```

then I have again to do this for `dim=4` and `dim ==2`
it is increasing too much code. So I tried to avoid if else check for dim by putting its value as :

```
std::string type = IOBase->GetComponentTypeAsString(IOBase->GetComponentType());
const unsigned int dim = IOBase->GetNumberOfDimensions();

if(type == "unsigned_char")
{
            typedef itk::Image<unsigned char,3> ImageType;
```

I have following situation:

```
  const unsigned int dimension = 3;
  itk::Image<unsigned char, dimension > image;
```

Here at time of execution I have to find what will be type and dimension then image will be created. When I run the above code it is working. But when I am trying to do this in following way:

```
const unsigned int dimension = FunctionGetDimension();
itk::Image<unsigned char, dimension > image;
```

it is not working even if I make return value of `FunctionGetDimension()` as const it is not working. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template arguments should be known at compile time, it is not possible to specify them at run time. Even though your `dim` is constant, it is not known at compile time.

Therefore anyway you need some more-or-less hand-made logic to create the `Image` object you need. A common approach to this is to create a factory.

The simplest type of factory is what I assume you already have — the chain of if/else if/else if... clauses, each returning an object of a different type. You just should better set it off to a separate function like following:

```
// I assume that itk::Image subclasses a non-template BasicImage
// if this is not the case, you will need some kind of a wrapper
// you should also return unique_ptr or its friends instead of raw pointer
BasicImage* createImage(int dim, std::string type) {
    if (dim == 3) {
        if (type == "unsigned_char")
            return new itk::Image<unsigned char, 3>();
        else if...
    } else if...
}
```

There are more advanced techniques of this: instead of hard-coded if/else chain, you can make it a class and keep a `std::map` of functions that create needed objects, and have objects themself register to it, see ["Factory Pattern"](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) and ["Factory Pattern in C++"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363338/Factory-Pattern-in-Cplusplus). This will not save much coding, because you will still have the code to register each class, but you can move this registration to better places and have some more advantages.

However, I would not overcomplicate things. As long as you understand how the factories work, you can start with a simple factory with hard-coded if/else chain, and later, if needed, switch to a factory using `map` and registrations without changing the factory's client interface. Just think of this interface in advance.

On contrary, if you have really many of variants of your template, you will not only need the implementation with `std::map`, but you will need to have the compiler handle registrationss for you. For this, you may  want to look at ["Subscribing Template Classes with Object Factories in C++"](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/subscription_problem.html) which describes a case very similar to yours, and adds some more advanced approaches.

Comment: To use a factory you'd need a type erased version of the `Image` object.

Comment: @petersohn, I know nothing of itk, but is there no such type-erased baseclass? If not, then I think it is impossible to have an `itk::Image` object with runtime-determined dimensions/type, as the object type should be known at compile time. At the same time, it might be possible to make a wrapper class around `Image` and have the factory work this way.

Comment: I don't know itk either. But sure, you can create such a wrapper if there is no base class.

Comment: there is a base class itkObjectFactory I guess you are talking about such stuff. These concept are new to me I have to study and I will try to implement.

Comment: I have to use this object through out the program and more like this will be created, I have to apply chain of operations those will also depend on pixel type and dimension. So do you feel factory interface would be better option?

Comment: @Tab, I have rewritten the answer and added some useful links